# Is there a way to abandon a diff via arc CLI?

Tags: command-line, phabricator

So far, the only way I found to close diffs is on the web ui. I have a workflow where I need to do this programatically, and would like to use the `arc` CLI to abandon diffs.

Is this possible? I tried reading through `arc -h` but didn't find anything related to abandoning diffs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
echo '{"transactions": [{"type": "abandon","value": true}], "objectIdentifier": "$REVISION"}' | arc call-conduit --conduit-uri https://$PHABRICATOR_DOMAIN.com/ differential.revision.edit
```